# View Change "On Submit" Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

Is there a way to do this without javascript?

Let me explain.  I have two models, users and dogs.

I'm using the index as a home page for when the users are logged in.

There is a form that searches dogs (not by any information the user enters, it's prepopulated with dog data), but the index is listing the result of my search query on page load.  I'd like it to only show when the button is submitted.

I'll show some code.

controller for dog:

```
def index
  if current_user
    @user = current_user
    @breed = @user.dogs.first.primarybreed
    # params[:search] = @breed
    @dog = Dog.search(params[:search]).sample
  end
end
```

view:

```
%= form_tag dogs_path, :method => :get do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :search, @breed %>
<%= image_submit_tag("/images/greenadd.png", size: "10x10", :name => nil) %> New Doggy Playdate!
<% end %>
<div id="dogswrap">

<h1><%= current_user.dogs[0].name %> Should Meet With...</h1>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= image_tag @dog.image.url(:medium) %></td>
    <td><%= @dog.name %></td>
    <td><%= @dog.nick %></td>
    <td><%= @dog.primarybreed %></td>
    <td><%= @dog.secondarybreed %></td>
    <td><%= @dog.age %></td>
    <td><%= @dog.weight %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "#{@dog.user.name}" %> </td>
    <td><%= image_tag @dog.user.image.url(:thumb) %> </td>

    </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Model

```
 def self.search(search)
    find(:all, :conditions => ['primarybreed LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
 end
```

I would like to have an if statement that shows the table only after the submit has been pushed.

If there is another way to do this, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Still working on this.  May use a render..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `where` in place of the way you're currently doing it `find` and `conditions`

```
def self.search(search)
  where('primarybreed LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
end
```

One thing I've learnt when using the `LIKE` function in development for SQLite3 and `LIKE` in PostgreSQL for production, was `LIKE` is case-insensitive in SQLite3 but not for PSQL. You would need to use `ILIKE` for that.

To your main question. This is how I would do it.

```
def index
  if current_user
    @user = current_user
    @dogs = Dog.search(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
  end
end
```

For you views, start moving everything into a partial. `_form.html.erb` and `_dog.html.erb`

form

```
<%= form_tag dogs_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search %>
  <%= image_submit_tag("/images/greenadd.png", size: "10x10", :name => nil) %> New Doggy Playdate!
<% end %>
```

dog

```
<td><%= image_tag dog.image.url(:medium) %></td>
<td><%= dog.name %></td>
<td><%= dog.nick %></td>
<td><%= dog.primarybreed %></td>
<td><%= dog.secondarybreed %></td>
<td><%= dog.age %></td>
<td><%= dog.weight %></td>
<td><%= link_to "#{dog.user.name}" %> </td>
<td><%= image_tag dog.user.image.url(:thumb) %></td>
```

Notice removed `@dog` and replaced with `dog`

Index view

```
<%= render 'form' %>
<div id="dogswrap">

<h1><%= @user.dogs[0].name %> Should Meet With...</h1>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <% if @dogs %>
      <%= render @dogs %>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

changed `current_user.dogs[0]..` to `@user.dogs[0]..` Also made a conditional for if the `@dogs` instance variable is truthy. If it is, then render will render out the `_dog.html.erb` partial for each dog in the `@dogs` collection